# What accounts for (u'',) in GET querystring values and why is it correctly parsed?

Tags: python, unicode, get

The Pingdom webhook API sends messages as `GET`s which look like this:

```
GET /17hfb1r1?message=(u'{"check": "1448865", "checkname": "Webhook Test Site - IGNORE", "host": "3eda0234.ngrok.com", "action": "assign", "incidentid": 335, "description": "down"}',)&aid=(u'monitoring',)
```

Note that each querystring parameter seems to be wrapped in `(u'',)`, which I thought was a Python thing (so possibly a bug in the Pingdom webhook implementation?).

Now, the odd thing is three different webhook receivers (i.e. HTTP servers) that I have tried, all **correctly handle** the `(u'',)` envelope. By correctly handle, I mean that they remove the envelope, leaving the containing values. These were:

1. [Requestbin](http://requestb.in/)
2. A Tomcat/Clojure Ring web server
3. A Scala Spray web server

The fact that all these handled it correctly makes me thing that `(u'',)` is an accepted envelope for `GET` querystring parameter values, but I can't find any documentation about this.

What could be generating a `(u'',)` envelope on Pingdom's side, and why is it tolerated by web servers?

Comment: Even if it's handled correctly on the receiving end, I would argue that it's bug in the sender (Pingdom) that is simply "prints" a Python tuple containing a single Unicode string.

Comment: Hi Joachim - we assumed it was a bug until we saw unilateral (well, in a sample of 3) support for it in web servers. Now my interest is piqued as to why!

Comment: @AlexDean  Is it possible that the `(u'',)` annotation is just a display issue.  I find it highly unlikely that those characters would be stripped off a URL.  The [Pingdom docs](https://support.pingdom.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/94/0/users-and-alerting-end-points) don't mention anything about those characters. If you want to be absolutely sure then you could use a [Runscope](http://www.runscope.com) proxy URL to watch the webhook request and see exactly what the URL is.

Comment: Hi @DarrelMiller - we haven't seen the (u'') annotation with any other webhook providers; also we don't have any Python in our stack, which reduces the number of places where it could be being introduced...

Comment: Hi @AlexDean - Actually, when I test `curl "http://requestb.in/xxxxxx?beep=meepmeep"` (where `xxxxxx` is my Requestbin bin), it shows: `GET /xxxxxx?beep=(u'meepmeep2',)`. Redirecting the curl to a local 'dumper' script (using Tornado) returns: `uri='/xxxxxx?beep=meepmeep2'`. So, I think that's the bug on Requestbin's side.

Comment: Hey @pepoluan - ah that makes sense and would explain the commonality. If you add that as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bug lies with [Requestbin](http://requestb.in/)'s implementation.

When I test with:

```
curl "http://requestb.in/xxxxxx?beep=meepmeep2"
```

Requestbin shows:

```
GET /xxxxxx?beep=(u'meepmeep2',)
```

However, redirecting the curl to a local 'dumper' script (using Tornado), I got:

```
uri='/xxxxxx?beep=meepmeep2'
```

(Note that in the comment, I accidentally deleted the number "2" after "meepmeep")

Comment: Sorry for the bug in RequestBin, we'll get that fixed up. https://www.runscope.com/docs/request-capture is a souped-up version of RequestBin that doesn't have the issue described.